# NodeMCU mqtt led brightness conrol

Tags: lua, nodemcu

Hi I want to control an led via mqtt but I can't find a way to set the led to the value that I send to the nodemcu. This is how I try to do it now but it can only do value 0 (then its off) or higher (then its on) and not dimmed.

```
if(topic=="ledstrip/red") {
  Serial.print("Changing RED Lights to ");
  if(messageTemp == "on"){
    for (int r = 0; r < 1023; r++) { 
      analogWrite(ledstrip_red, r);
      delay(1);
    }
    digitalWrite(ledstrip_red, HIGH);
    Serial.print("On");
  } else if(messageTemp == "off"){
    digitalWrite(ledstrip_red, HIGH);
    for (int r = 1023; r > 0; r--) { 
      analogWrite(ledstrip_red, r);
      delay(1);
    } 
    digitalWrite(ledstrip_red, LOW);
    Serial.print("Off");
  } else {
    Serial.print("Changing RED Brightness to ");
    digitalWrite(ledstrip_red, messageTemp.toInt());
    Serial.print(messageTemp);       
}
```

Comment: Can I suggest you go do some research on PWM

Comment: I know what pwm is

Comment: Then you know how to solve this problem

Comment: No normally if you do digitalWrite(ledstrip_red, 1023); it goes fully on right? But why not when I take the message and put that in the place off 1023

Comment: `digitalWrite()` can only set the value to 0 or 1

Comment: Thank you I completely forgot about that i have to use analogwrite for brightness now it works

Comment: Sorry for asking such a dumb question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`digitalWrite()` can only set the value to 0 or 1